Reset/Restart Flow In Lightning Web Component after After Errors
We are running a flow in a Lightning Web Component. This flow runs when the component is loaded in another LWC. The flow can throw an exception like the below image while running.

How can we reset/re-start the flow after the error is thrown?
I have tried to use Refresh Event to reload the LWC, but it does not work. Is there any workaround or solution?
